# Add the "Inter-App Audio" entitlement to your entitlements file

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, core-audio, audiotoolbox

I am trying to add inter-app audio support to my app. I've enabled it in my App-ID in the iOS Portal, then in XCode 5 -> Capabilities, I've toggled the Inter-App Audio switch to on. There are 3 things it tries to do. See photo:

[image]

I've searched high and low for this topic but can't find anything of value.

I have the code signing and provisioning profile setup correctly and even did a test submit to iTunesConnect. I can't get this enabled.

I've seen how to make entitlement files, but have not idea what to put in it for this.

Any help/hints appreciated. Thanks.

Update: I found and apple sample project for this. They had an entitlements file so I copied it (renamed appropriately). See photos:

[image]
[image]

However this doesn't remove the error.

Comment: What happens when you click the Fix Issue button? Just curious...

Comment: It gives the typical "Your developer account needs to be updated. Please visit membercenter". I've gone there and it all looks fine. I've even regenerated my certs and such.

Answer (score 1):

Refreshing your provisioning profiles may fix the issue.

Here are the steps:

1. Xcode Preferences
2. Accounts tab
3. Select your Apple ID
4. Hit the View Details button in the Apple ID detail panel
5. Hit the Refresh button in the lower left corner